Gauss milton Newton
This is my code. I don't know what the problem is; it's giving me results that don't make sense,
The code begins by initializing the simulation parameters, such as the sample size (N), the number of repetitions (Nr), the number of dimensions for the points P, and the coordinates of different targets (P1 to P4). Then, it initializes matrices to store the results and defines parameters for the Gauss-Newton algorithm, such as the number of iterations. The code loops over different sample sizes (N) and performs an internal loop for each sample size and each repetition. At each iteration, it generates observed data (z) by adding Gaussian noise to the distance between an estimated point (P_estim) and the target points (P1 to P4). Then, it uses the Gauss-Newton algorithm to estimate the parameters (P_estim) by minimizing the error between the observed data and the distances to the target points. It stores the mean squared errors for each sample size and repetition. Finally, the code plots a graph comparing the mean squared errors and the Cramér-Rao bound as a function of the sample size for different covariance matrices.

clear all
close all

% Simulation
N = 3:10:1000;
Nr = 100;
num_dimensions = 4;  % Number of dimensions for points P

% Initialize coordinates of a target
P1 = [4, 5, 6]';
P2 = [7, 8, 9]';
P3 = [10, 11, 12]';
P4 = [4; 3; 2];
P_ = {P1, P2, P3, P4};

% Covariance matrix
sigma_values = 0.0001;

% Initialize matrices to store results
num_N = numel(N);
num_sigma_values = 1;
P_estims = zeros(num_N, num_dimensions, num_sigma_values);
mean_errs_all = cell(num_sigma_values, 1); % Cell vector to store quadratic errors for each sigma value

% Gauss-Newton algorithm parameters
num_iterations = 50;

% Loop over different sample sizes
for k = 1:num_sigma_values
    mean_errs_sigma_k = zeros(num_N, Nr); % Initialize vector to store quadratic errors for sigma k
    
    for i = 1:num_N
        for nr = 1:Nr
            sigma = sigma_values(k);
            % Initialize parameters to estimate
            P = [1; 0; 3];  % Initialize P
            
            for l = 1:num_dimensions
                z(l) = sqrt(sum((P - P_{l}).^2)) + randn * sigma;

            end
            z = z';
            P_estim = P + randn;
            err_algo(1) = norm(P_estim - P);
            % Gauss-Newton
            for iter = 2:num_iterations
                % Calculate distances between P_estim and each point P_i
                distances = zeros(num_dimensions, 1);
                for l = 1:num_dimensions
                    distances(l) = norm(P_estim - (P_{l}));
                end
                
                % Calculate error
                error = zeros(num_dimensions, 1);
                for l = 1:num_dimensions
                    error(l) = z(l) - distances(l);
                end
                
                % Calculate Jacobian matrix
                J_h = zeros(num_dimensions, 3);
                
                for l = 1:num_dimensions
                    J_h(l, :) = -(P_estim - (P_{l}))' / norm(P_estim - (P_{l}));
                end
                
                % Update P with Gauss-Newton method
                delta_P = -(J_h' * J_h)^-1 * (J_h' * error);
                P_estim = P_estim + delta_P;
                err_algo(iter) = norm(P_estim - P);
                
            end

            % Parameter estimation
            % P_estims(i, :, k) = P_estim;

            % Calculate quadratic error for this simulation realization
            mean_errs_sigma_k(i, nr) = norm(P - P_estim)^2;
        end
    end
    
    mean_errs_all{k} = mean_errs_sigma_k;
end


% Initialize vectors to store N and CRB values
N_values = zeros(num_N, 1);
cramer_rao_values = zeros(num_N, 1);

% Plot graph comparing mean errors and CRB versus N
for k = 1:num_sigma_values
    % Plot mean quadratic error
    plot(N, mean(mean_errs_all{k}, 2), 'o-', 'LineWidth', 2); %
    hold on;

    % Calculate and plot Cramér-Rao bound for each N value
    for i = 1:num_N
        J_h = zeros(num_dimensions, 3);
        for l = 1:num_dimensions
            J_h(l, :) = (P - (P_{l}))' / norm(P - (P_{l}));
        end
        cramer_rao_bound = inv(J_h.' * J_h) * sigma_values^2 / N(i);
        
        % Store N and CRB values
        N_values(i) = N(i);
        cramer_rao_values(i) = trace(cramer_rao_bound); % Store current CRB value
    end
    
    % Plot CRB
    plot(N_values, cramer_rao_values, 'o--', 'LineWidth', 2);
end

xlabel('Sample Size (N)');
ylabel('Mean Quadratic Errors / CRB');
title('Comparison of Mean Quadratic Errors and CRB versus N for Different Covariance Matrices');
legend('Mean Quadratic Error', 'Cramér-Rao Bound');


This MATLAB code conducts a simulation to estimate the parameters of a model based on observed data, employing the Gauss-Newton algorithm. By executing this code, one can gain insights into the accuracy and efficiency of the parameter estimation process across diverse conditions. These conditions include alterations in sample sizes and levels of noise, which are represented by arrays in the algorithm. This process is relevant to fields such as mathematics, statistics, and computer science, particularly in the domain of numerical methods and statistical inference.
running this code will provide insights into the accuracy and efficiency of the parameter estimation process under different conditions, such as varying sample sizes and levels of noise

it's giving me results that don't make sense, provide those results and why (you think) they don't make sense.

Also, is your title wrong ? You are using Gauss-Newton algorithm, not Gauss-Milton :)

you can use my code and see results that gives

i dont now if its my code is good or not
